# TFS 2015 Git Repository Build Get only Relevant files

Tags: git, build, tfs-2015

Recently I have been configuring TFS 2015 Git Repository for my company. I have a 8GB main branch with multiple solutions in it. Every solution should be build seperately. Every solution does not need all the data in this branch. Is there a way to configure build each solution only gets related files not whole branch ?

Also my solutions have 5 folders , 1 folder has references to other four. Only this one folder's built version is what I am looking for. Is there a way to tell "only drop this folder for me" ?

Comment: Your build plan does not necessarily have anything to do with Git.  Git says how and what files get versioned, not which files are included in a particular build (maybe I am missing something).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it does due to the fact that cloning a repository will always get the full repository. It isn't even possible to just grab a single branch. But what it can do is to perform a shallow clone, only cloning the latest version of the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, we found the solution. When choosig the source folder on the Copy stage I chose only the subfolder I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The way cloning a git repository works it will always get the whole repository, there is no way around that other than splitting up your solutions into separate repo's and using something like NuGet packages to re-use the output from one build into anther build.

As such there is no way to tell the build agent to only fetch specific files.

To improve the performance, make sure your build agent doesn't delete the repository after a build and is able to re-use the existing clone. That way it only has to fetch the delta, making it much, much faster.

To only publish the files you're after, adjust the "Copy and publish" task at the end of your build to use a different source path. That part is possible and quite simple to achieve.

Comment: By adding rules on the Retention tab I can add a rule which allows me to exclude Branches. I hope this could help. Thanks for anwering my question.

Comment: then why it exist anyway !

Comment: I just checked and I think you're looking at the "Branch Filters", which don't do what you expect them to do. They allow you to configure to builds from which branch the retention policy applies. It allows you to say for example that builds from branch master are retained for 2 years. And builds from a feature branch are deleted after 7 days.

Comment: anyway there is no solution suggestions to my problem.

Comment: As I said. This is how it is supposed to work and there is no way to work around it.